Scammers trap. Need help with funds withdrawal from a contract that was deployed by me
I’m looking for an advice. Probably I know an answer but maybe there is a chance to withdraw my funds from the contract I deployed. Here below are some facts about that.
Site: Remixide.fo (Now I know that it’s a fake remix)
Link to the scammer’s code that I’ve used to create a contract: https://pastebin.com/raw/jhsTquwE
Contract address: 0x402Dd552136764Af2aa69586481576e7C1de9D23
Contract creator: my MetaMask wallet address.
YouTube link on a scammer’s video: https://youtu.be/AyZduX7zUdY?si=AWRBd7SR-_cowJQo
Is it somehow possible to withdraw my funds back?
Thank you in advance.

I had a look.
The contract does have a few functions to withdraw assets. But the receiver of the assets is basically hardcoded and you can't influence that. So you can only trigger the sending to the scammer's address - not to yourself or anyone else.
Sorry for your loss.

Thank you for the answer. Is it possible to freeze these funds in order not to give an opportunity for scammers to get them?

No. The contract is what it is, and it doesn't have the possibility to freeze anything.

Sorry to read that. Thanks a lot.
